# require.js, am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm new to require.js and found the documentation quite hard to understand. After a while I got my project up and running with the following setup.

```
project
    |
    |--js
        |--vendor
            |--require.js
            |--modernizr.js
            |--jquery.js
        |--modules
            |--module1.js
            |--module2.js
        |--main.js
    |--index.html
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script data-main="/js/main.js" src="/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
define([
    "vendor/modernizr",
    "modules/module1",
    "modules/module2"
]);
```

modules/module1.js

```
define(['vendor/jquery'], function () {
    // Some module code like
    $('#button').on('click', function(){});
});
```

Is this a good setup if I like to have one import file (main.js) like in a less setup for CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup is generally in the right direction, just some slight modifications need to be made.

For the modules, you need to pass in a matching number of arguments for each dependency of the module. In this case, you would want to assign `$` to what is returned by the jQuery module, so that you can actually use `$` within the module:

```
define(['vendor/jquery'], function ($) {
    // Some module code like
    $('#button').on('click', function(){});
});
```

For main.js, the `define()` call should be a `require()` call so that you will be executing whatever's in the module instead of simply registering it a module for some other module to execute:

```
require([
    "vendor/modernizr",
    "modules/module1",
    "modules/module2"
], function(Modernizr, module1, module2) {
   // do something with Modernizr, module1, module2
});
```